# Why do we need an adiabatic expansion in the Carnot cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, adiabatic, carnot-cycle

As we know that 1st process is an reversible isothermal expansion during this the system is in quasi static equilibrium which helps in increasing the volume of the system but why does the second step need an adiabatic expansion like why do we need an second step as the heat absorbed is equal to the work produced

Comment: See also [Why does adiabatic expansion occur in the carnot process?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/715558/146039), [Why does adiabatic expansion occur in the Carnot cycle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/778664/why-does-adiabatic-expansion-occur-in-the-carnot-cycle),[my own answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/778666/146039).

Answer (score 0):

The carnot cycle is theoretically the highest efficiency engine that can be achieved. As you stated, the first part is an isothermal expansion which allows for an increase in volume. However, if we compressed this directly, some of the heat would be rejected. This is where the Adiabatic expansion comes in.
It expands further without exchange of heat (Due to Adiabatic nature of the expansion) which allows the internal energy to drop. *ΔU = ΔQ-ΔW*
Hence, this results in a temperature drop as the internal energy available for thermal motion reduces.
In Summary, for efficiency we need most percentage of heat given out to be converted into work and thus the carnot cycle's Adiabatic expansion aids in it.